# created a function in SQL Server but can't call it from SP?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I created a function in my SQL Server 2008 using the code here:
http://www.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx

I see it in my DB under Programability > Functions > Table-valued Functions > dbo.Split

but when I try and call in in my SP code:

```
SELECT ItemID
  FROM StagingCategoryItems 
 WHERE ManufacturerID = @ManufacturerID 
   AND CategoryID = @CategoryID
   AND ItemID IN (    
                  dbo.Split(@InIds,',')
                 )
```

I get this error:

```
Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.Split", or the name is ambiguous.
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the function as a tablename in the select clause as it is a table valued function.

Try this:

```
SELECT ItemID  
  FROM StagingCategoryItems 
 WHERE ManufacturerID = @ManufacturerID 
   AND CategoryID = @CategoryID  
   AND ItemID IN (SELECT items
                    FROM dbo.Split(@InIds,',')     
                 )
```

Comment: +1 beat me to it, you might want to mention something about the difference in how table valued functions get called vs scalar functions

Comment: doh! Thank you, I wasn't paying attention or reading very thoroughly.